# Unknown column in 'where clause' | with where or & joins

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3, php-7.1

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'FI_t1.messageID' in 'on clause'
Line Number: 102
"$query = $this->db->get('community_messages t1', 1);"

`SELECT t1.*, t2.toUserID, max(unread) as unread, parentID, deleted, FI_users.userID, email, firstName, lastName, displayName, avatar FROM`FI_community_messagest1`JOIN`FI_community_messagemapt2`ON`t2`.`messageID`=`FI_t1`.`messageID`JOIN`FI_users`ON`FI_users`.`userID`=`FI_t1`.`userID`WHERE t1.siteID = 1 AND deleted = 0 AND (t2.toUserID = 3 OR t2.userID = 3) GROUP BY`messageID`LIMIT 1`

-

So the function in question is **this**(https://pastebin.com/haG1ybF7)

Note this was working fine on CodeIgniter 2
encountered this a lot and what seemed to make it work was specifying the from and limit after the select, also ordering the get and join.

So changed the function to **this**(https://pastebin.com/MeH5aBKH).

Although this works totally fine, I can't help but feel there's a better way of doing this that would make it more readable and easy to understand.
This is important as it's on an opensource project for others to use too.

Kind regards.

Comment: Yeah the second function example shows how I got it working but I was wanting maybe a more detailed better example.

Comment: In theory using the CI DB classes is beneficial, as you could decide that you wanted to switch from MySQL to SQLite3 to XYZ, and you only have to learn how to use the CI DB classes. For me, I do like using CI DB's insert and update methods, and I use the query method a lot, but I mostly write my own SQL. It's just so much easier, and 1000% cleaner to look at, debug, etc. If your open source project makes it more or less mandatory for people to use MySQL, then you might consider doing that.